# Have both Aggregate Initialization and Template Deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-deduction, aggregate-initialization

### Background:

C++17 has two great features: **aggregate initialization** and **template type deduction** (for classes). Aggregate initialization allows you to instantiate fields without copying or moving them, and template type deduction makes it so that you don't have to specify the type of your argument.

The `Wrapper` class in the below code is an example of this. As long as `HAVE_MOVE_AND_COPY` is left undefined, it has aggregate initialization, but then template type deduction doesn't work.

On the other hand, if `HAVE_MOVE_AND_COPY` *is* defined, then template type deduction works, but aggregate initialization breaks. How can I have both?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

template<class T> 
struct Wrapper {
    T value;
   #ifdef HAVE_MOVE_AND_COPY
    Wrapper(T const & val) : value{val} {}
    Wrapper(T && val) : value{std::move(val)} {}
   #endif
    Wrapper(Wrapper const &) = default;
    Wrapper(Wrapper &&) = default;
    

};

struct VocalClass {
    VocalClass() { puts("VocalClass()"); }
    VocalClass(VocalClass const&) { puts("VocalClass(VocalClass const &)"); }
    VocalClass(VocalClass &&) { puts("VocalClass(VocalClass &&)"); }
};

int main() {
    Wrapper<VocalClass> w { VocalClass() }; 

   #ifdef TRY_DEDUCTION
    Wrapper w2 { VocalClass() }; 
   #endif
}
```

### Example:

#### No moving or copying occurs, but you don't have template deduction:

```
$ c++ -std=c++17 example.cc && ./a.out
VocalClass()
```

#### Has template deduction, but `VocalClass` gets moved:

```
$ c++ -DHAVE_MOVE_AND_COPY -DTRY_DEDUCTION -std=c++17 example.cc && ./a.out 
VocalClass()
VocalClass(VocalClass &&)
VocalClass()
VocalClass(VocalClass &&)
```

#### Without `HAVE_MOVE_AND_COPY`, template type deduction breaks:

```
sky@sunrise:~$ c++ -DTRY_DEDUCTION -std=c++17 example.cc && ./a.out 
example.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
example.cc:27:31: error: class template argument deduction failed:
     Wrapper w2 { VocalClass() };
                               ^
example.cc:27:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘Wrapper(VocalClass)’
example.cc:12:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class T> Wrapper(Wrapper<T>&&)-> Wrapper<T>’
     Wrapper(Wrapper &&) = default;
     ^~~~~~~
example.cc:12:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
example.cc:27:31: note:   ‘VocalClass’ is not derived from ‘Wrapper<T>’
     Wrapper w2 { VocalClass() };
                               ^
example.cc:11:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class T> Wrapper(const Wrapper<T>&)-> Wrapper<T>’
     Wrapper(Wrapper const &) = default;
     ^~~~~~~
example.cc:11:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
example.cc:27:31: note:   ‘VocalClass’ is not derived from ‘const Wrapper<T>’
     Wrapper w2 { VocalClass() };
                               ^
example.cc:5:8: note: candidate: ‘template<class T> Wrapper(Wrapper<T>)-> Wrapper<T>’
 struct Wrapper {
        ^~~~~~~
example.cc:5:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
example.cc:27:31: note:   ‘VocalClass’ is not derived from ‘Wrapper<T>’
     Wrapper w2 { VocalClass() };
```

### Question

Is there any way I can have both template type deduction, and aggregate initialization?

Comment: Your type is not an aggregate if it has a user-declared destructor (which it does in both cases) so it cannot be aggregate-initialized.

Comment: Okay. What term should I use to describe a class that permits copy and move elison when being constructed? Also, how does Wrapper have a user declared destructor?

Answer (score 5):

First, the term is "class template argument deduction."

Second, what you need is a *deduction guide*:

```
template<class T> 
struct Wrapper {
    T value;
};

template <typename T>
Wrapper(T) -> Wrapper<T>; // this is a deduction guide
```

Without a constructor, you need some other way to guide deduction. That's what this is there for, and it allows:

```
Wrapper w{4}; // ok, Wrapper<int>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a misunderstanding of what the term "aggregate" means.

Firstly, what you are doing is called list-initialization. List-initialization will only aggregate-initialize your instance if the type of the instance is an aggregate. Aggregate-initialization allows you to initialize the base classes and/or members of your class in order with an initializer list.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

> An aggregate is one of the following types:
>
> - array type
> - class type (typically, struct or union), that has
>
>   - no user-provided, inherited, or explicit constructors (explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed)
> - no virtual, private, or protected (since C++17) base classes
> - no virtual member functions
> - no default member initializers

The second bullet-point applies here. Since you have a user-provided constructor (a constructor written out by the user instead of generated by the compiler) when `HAVE_MOVE_AND_COPY` is defined, your type is not an aggregate and the compiler will only look for constructors to initialize your instance.

Barry covers the rest about how to make an aggregate with class template argument deduction.